# Email Service with Delivery to Subset of Recipients

Tags: email

Is there a reputable email sending service that provides a HTTP API that can take an email, but only deliver to a subset of the recipients?

For example, I've got an email like this:

```
To: Alice, Bob, Carol
Cc: Dan
Subject: Whatever
```

Now I only want this email to be delivered to Alice and Dan, but I still want Bob and Carol to be on the To line.

Answer (score 0):

Most email services use SMTP protocol for email sending.  SMTP does not force recipients in command `RCPT TO:` to be related to recipients listed in `TO:`, `CC:`, `BCC:` headers.

Name Operating System or Linux distribution you use to get recommendations of email clients with such functionality
**OR**
use scripting language like perl or python.

Comment: Clarified question, I'm looking for an HTTP API, not running my own SMTP relay.